# Keras theano prediction using cpu

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, grid, theano

I am working on my university cluster and I am trying to import my keras model into an analyzer to get some predictions.

The cluster only has cpu's and I don't have access to CUDA or any GPU's for running my model and making predictions.

I am currently able to make predictions by loading the model json and weights, but I get the following message while execution:

```
cc1plus: fatal error: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
ERROR:theano.sandbox.cuda] Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu
```

I have seen others have same error but the solution doesn't apply to me because I do not have /user/local/cuda/ and I can't change it.

I set the device to cpu hoping this was the problem but it's not the case:

```
theano.config.device='cpu'
```

What should I do?

Comment: What are the contents of your theanorc? (the file ~/.theanorc)

Comment: Why you still use theano? (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/theano-users/7Poq8BZutbY/rNCIfvAEAwAJ). Captain Obvious recommends TensorFlow for CPU.